# How are Java ByteBuffer's limit and position variable's updated?

Tags: java, file-handling, file-storage, io

There are two scenarios: writing and reading
**Writing**:
Whenever I write something to the ByteBuffer by calling its `put(byte[])` method the `position` variable is incremented as: `current position + size of byte[]` and `limit` stays at the max.
If, however, I put the data in a view buffer then I will have to, manually, calculate and update the `position`
Before I call the `write(ByteBuffer)` method of the channel to write something, I will have to `flip()` the Bytebuffer so that
`position` points to zero and `limit` points to the last byte that was written to the ByteBuffer.
**Reading**:
Whenever I call the `read(ByteBuffer)` method of a channel to read something, the `position` variable stays at 0 and the `limit` variable of the ByteBuffer points to the last byte that was read. So, if the ByteBuffer is smaller than the file being read, the `limit` variable is pushed to max
This means that the ByteBuffer is already flipped and I can proceed to extracting the values from the ByteBuffer.
**Please, correct me where I am wrong** :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you read from or write to the buffer, only it's position changes.

So you are wrong about reading from channel. Note that reading from channel means *writing* to the buffer. You can set the position to 0 and limit - to the maximum number of bytes to read *before* you call `Channel.read(ByteBuffer)`. The read operation then updates the position to the number of bytes actually read. So, to start reading from buffer you have to call `ByteBuffer.flip()`.

Comment: so basically, nothing affects the `limit` variable

Comment: Right. The documentation states this as: "_A buffer's limit is the index of the first element that should not be read or written._"